# Different rules predict contradictory directions of torque

Tags: rotational-dynamics, vectors, rotation

Consider a coordinate system set up as follows:

[image]

One way to find the direction of the torque is to find the algebraic sign of the component of torque along the axis of rotation.

> We can assign an algebraic sign to the vector component
> of a torque along any axis by regarding that torque
> component as positive if it tends to produce counterclockwise
> rotations when viewed from along that axis, and negative
> if it tends to produce clockwise rotations.

(Rule source: Halliday, Resnick, Krane - Physics Volume 1, Edition 5)

The angle is increasing in the counter-clockwise direction, thus the above rule predicts that the torque component should be positive, which means that the torque should point in the +Z direction.

Using the right-hand rule for vector cross products, we find that the torque should point in the -Z direction.

This appears to be a conflict. Where am I going wrong? Also, why is *when viewed from along that axis* stated in the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the *x* and *y* vectors form a horizontal plane, and that *x* is closer to the observer than *y*, then the posted coordinate system is a *left-handed* system. You cannot apply the *right-hand* rule to a left-handed system.

The following is a right hand system which has $\hat{z} = \hat{x} \times \hat{y}$, by flipping the direction of the *z* axis to be along the direction of the thumb if you use your right-hand too sweep from *x* to *y* with your fingers.

[image: this]

Comment: Actually you can't tell from either diagram whether they are rh or lh systems. But with x and y as normally drawn, so z is our of the page, both right hand rules give the same results. Perhaps your view switched between the two aspects.

Comment: The assumption here is that the _x_ axis is closer to the observer than the _y_ axis.